# OSX Network: "could not save because write access was not granted"

Tags: macos, network, osx-server, leopard

We have a really basic network of Macs here in our studio. We keep all our files on a machine running Leopard server, but we're all on Lion.

The problem we're having is every single time we open a file and then try to save it, we get the error

```
Could not save <FILENAME> because write access was not granted.
```

The easy work around is to do a save as. The weird thing is if you simply close the file without doing a save as, it disappears from the folder it was in.

I didn't set up our server, but I know we tried to enable all the permissions we could for every user. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are the users network users or local users?

Comment: In what programs is this occurring?

Answer (score 1):

There are Apple-created bugs in OS X 10.5 "Leopard" client & server when copying files to/from AFP shared volumes.

See more detail in this answer:

[No right to open file once copied on the desktop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83317/no-right-to-open-file-once-copied-on-the-desktop)